# I am getting error while importing a file.So How do i solve?

Tags: python, selenium, importerror

I am getting below error code.I don't have any much experience about python.Please help me.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'geckodriver' from 'selenium' (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\__init__.py)
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are trying to do something like

```
from selenium import gekodriver
```

There is no gekodriver method in selenium class ,. You should use

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

If you want to open firefox